# Jquery UI Slider Value inside Handle

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I have a jquery slider and it's styled in that the value is inside the handle.  I have a script which works on days selected in this slider, but I want to display the days within the handle.

I've tried this but it doesn't work.

```
$("#slider2").slider({
    max:30,
    min:7,

    slide: function(event, ui) {  

        $("#days").val(ui.value);
        $("#date").html(addDaysToDate(parseInt($("#days sliderControl-label v-labelCurrent unit").val())));
                update();
    },
    create: function(event, ui) {
      $("#date").html(addDaysToDate(parseInt($("#days sliderControl-label v-labelCurrent unit").val())));
    }    
});
```

Here is a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jonnystudent/6hyVP/15/).  So In the handle, it should look like this [image: Days button], with the count going up to 30 days.

Cheers,

Jonah

Comment: Any help would be helpful for this.  Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Your code had references to ids of non-existent elements ("amount2", "date", etc).

And also, I think you referenced the slider with an id "days", also non-existent.

In [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6hyVP/107/), I left a somewhat working example, that updated the current slider value inside the handle. This was made just by giving this handle an id:

```
<div id="slider2"><a id="days" class="ui-slider-handle"></a></div>
```

and updating properly its value inside the slide event of the slider:

```
$("#days").html(ui.value);
```